# collate conflict in case operator

Tags: sql

Всем привет! Не могу решить проблему, связанную с кодом ниже, заранее спасибо!

```
select
  case
    when t.doc collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS = 'some value'
      then 8
    else null
  end,
from table_one tbl (nolock)
join #table t
    on tbl.sname = t.sname collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS 
    and convert(varchar, tbl.dates, 104) = convert(varchar(10), t.dates)
```

Error:

```
Msg 457, Level 16, State 1, Line 104
Implicit conversion of text value to text cannot be performed because the collation of the value is unresolved due to a collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS" in CASE operator.
```

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал у 'some value' тоже collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS написать, например, для начала.

Comment: Вообще у базы какой дефолтный collate?

Comment: Вроде вменяемо пишется: *collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS" in CASE operator.* CASE тут один-единственный, сравнение в нём одно, из двух операндов один явно приводится к Cyrillic_General_CI_AS - значит, именно второй SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS. А литералы, емнип, имеют Collation соединения.

Comment: Уже как только не пробовал, вообще не идет..

Comment: `when t.doc collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS = 'some value' collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`

Comment: не, оказалось дичь дичевая, в итоге та было еще одно поле после запятой кейса, и вот у него добавление коллейта помогло, не стал его писать, так как подумал что из содержания описания ошибки проблема в кейсе, Всем спасибо..